# Is Windows 2003 Server still supported?

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am looking at this page ( http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?LN=en-us&x=7&y=17&p1=3198 ) but I can't figure out the answer to this question.  Suppose we have a Windows 2003 Server with the latest service pack.  Is it still supported?

Answer (score 5):

Windows server 2003 is in extended support. Support will officially end July 14, 2015

http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifean36

Answer (score 5):

From the Microsoft page that you linked to:

> Support ends 24 months after the next service pack releases or at the
>   end of the product's support lifecycle, whichever comes first.

SP2 is the final Service Pack available for Server 2003. You will lose support when Server 2003 as a platform is no longer supported. It was released on 3/30/2005 so it has mainstream support until 3/30/2010. You will have to deal with the extended support restrictions through 3/30/2015.

[image]

Here's the feature matrix for the extended support phase:

[image]